# Which Chess Notation is Most Commonly Used in Grandmaster Classic Games?

Tags: analysis, theory, history, grandmaster, notation

I'm interested in understanding the preferred method of notation used in classic games played by grandmasters. Specifically, I'd like to know which version of writing the moves of a game is more common in high-level play such as grandmaster tournaments.

Is there a particular style or format of notation that is predominantly used in these settings?

Answer (score 3):

[Algebraic notation](https://rcc.fide.com/appendixc/) is the official notation of FIDE; if a player records the game in a different notation system, their scoresheet may not be used as evidence in the event of a dispute.

> I'm interested in understanding the preferred method of notation used in classic games played by grandmasters.

The notation is the same for everyone, regardless of their title(s).